# Can I shortcut-check if a variable is `nil` and replace by a default value?

Tags: ruby, null

Is there a way to shortcut-check if a variable is `nil`, and give a default value if it is? For instance, replace

```
result = (var == nil ? defaultvalue : var)
```

with something like

```
result = selfifnotnil(var, default)
```

Of course I could write `selfifnotnil` function like the ternary above, but is there any built in option?

Comment: Can `var` possibly be `false`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's as simple as this (assuming that `false` and `nil` are treated the same)

```
result = var || defaultvalue
```

If `false` is a legitimate value (not a missing one), then you have to do that ternary.

```
 result = var.nil? ? defaultvalue : var
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `nil` is a falsely value. Therefore:

```
result = var || defaultvalue
```

Comment: I've seen some programmers use `result || = default`. Am I correct in assuming it's the same thing?

Comment: @VictoriaS. That is syntactic sugar for `result = result || default`

Comment: @VictoriaS.: almost. Here it's not applicable, because another var is checked for value, not `result`

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for clarifying! :)

Answer (score 1):

Or if it is to check the var itself and assign default value. Also, if you are from another language, be careful which values are false in ruby.

```
result ||= default
```